# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

This is probably a really basic question, but when I make my `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` instance (addBookViewer)visible by running,

```
[self presentModalViewController:addBookViewer animated:YES]
```

the contact view pops up, but is cut off by the top most bar of the display (the bar showing the AT&T signal strength, clock and battery charge).  Is there a way to programatically change the addBookViewer so that it is not cut off by the static status bar?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [`ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) inherits from [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW2). Perhaps you could try editing the view's frame before presenting it:

```
addBookViewer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 20);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it didn't seem to fix the sizing issue.

Comment: I would recommend that you also visit Apple's developer forums: http://devforums.apple.com/ They answer lots of questions there.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is because the view controller that you are calling `presentModalViewController:animated:` on has a frame that is also being covered, but you don't notice, probably have plenty of head room, make sure you have the status bar in your nib file so that it is laid out correctly.